# bootstrap dropdown ::after pseudo-element align right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using `btn-block` on my `.dropdown-toggle` button to make it the full width.

However, I don't like how the ::after pseudo element only sits a fixed width away from the button content.

I am weak with psuedo element styling but is there a way that I can get the dropdown arrow to 'float' and be aligned a fixed width from the right side of the dropdown?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the `:after` element `position: absolute;` and align it to the right like so...

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

The `top` and `margin-top` elements are to help vertically align the arrow no matter the height of the dropdown.